# Is the getc and putc implementation of K&R right?

Tags: c, getc

In the K&R, chapter 8, it has a custom implementation of the putc and getc functions. In the first definition of getc, if the parameter is stdin, according to the definition of _iob, the function will try to write in the address 0 because this is the value which _iob[0].ptr and _iob[0].base were assigned. Is this legal?

Code: http://ideone.com/AIkCA

Definition of _iob:

```
FILE _iob[20] = {
 {0, (char *) 0, (char *) 0, _READ, 0},
 {0, (char *) 0, (char *) 0, _WRITE, 0},
 {0, (char *) 0, (char *) 0, _WRITE, 0}
};
```

Comment: Why don't you post the code in your question and tell us what edition of the book are you using? I assume that not everyone here has a copy of the book handy to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: I case of any future questions of this type, there is an errata page for K&R2 at <http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html> - at least, there was. It seems to be down right now. Google cache has it though. (*enormous URL omitted*) If you found any errors not yet discovered, the C programming world will be shocked. It is called our Bible after all. We've studied it *hard*.

Comment: The cm.bell-labs.com site is back up now and the link still doesn't work. Here it is again: http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html

Comment: @AlanCurry is the implementation of `putc(x, p)` right? Shouldn't it be the 'opposite' of `getc()`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we both have the same code in front of us, the answer is no.

```
#define getc(p)  (--(p)->cnt >= 0 \
  ? (unsigned char) *(p)->ptr++ : _fillbuf(p))
```

`stdin` is initialized with `cnt==0`, so this definition of `getc` will branch to `_fillbuf` (without looking at `(p)->ptr`), and `_fillbuf` has special code for the `fp->base == NULL` case and sets both `base` and `ptr` to allocated memory.

Comment: Thanks, I explained the same thing in my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time following what's being asked, but from the use of "custom" in the question, one angle to look at this from is whether replacing `getc` and `putc` with these definitions on an existing system is valid, and the answer is no. The example in K&R is showing you one way to go about writing the stdio library, not something that can work with an existing (possibly very different) implementation of stdio.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I was wrong.

In the first call of getc(stdin), the counter will be 0 so --(p)->cnt will not be >= 0 so the _fillbuf will be called. Then fillbuf will allocate buffer and then it will read from stdin with the read command (fp->cnt = read(fp->fd, fp->ptr, bufsize).